# Alternate to Toast.Forms.Plugin for Xamarin Forms App

Tags: plugins, xamarin.forms

I have been using Egor Bogatov's Toasts.Forms.Plugin v2.0.4 to display success/failure/info messages to users.  After migrating to .Net Standard I needed to upgrade the plugin, since that version supports .Net Framework.  Unfortunately the 3+ version has morphed into a notification framework and does not fit our needs.  Is there an alternate plugin that supports .Net Standard and simply displays a message for a set length of time?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Plugin.Toast v 2.1.1 to display message, warning, error success and create your custom toast. It's available for iOS and Android projects